# Natural sort for SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, sorting, dataview, natural-sort

### Similar Questions

Similar questions have been asked before, but always have specific qualities to the data which allow a more targeted "split it up and just sort by this part" approach, which does not work when you don't know the structure of the data in the column - or even the column, frankly. In other words, not a generic, "Natural" sort order - something roughly equivalent to `SELECT * FROM [parts] ORDER BY [part_category] DESC, [part_number] NATURAL DESC`

### My Situation

I have a DataView in C# that has a `Sort` parameter for specifying the `ORDER BY` that would be used by ADO, and a requirement to sort by a column using a 'natural' sort algorithm. I could in theory do just about anything from creating a different column to sort by (based on the column I'd like to have 'sorted naturally') to not sorting in SQL, but rather sorting the result set in code afterwards. I'm looking for the best balance of flexibility, efficiency, preparation effort, and maintainability. I would benefit somewhat from being able to sort such data after retrieval (in C#) or completely within a stored procedure.

In my mind, and according to customer statements so far, 'Natural' sort order will mean treating upper and lower case letters equivalently, and considering the *magnitude* of a number, rather than the ASCII value of its digits (that is `x90` comes *before* `x100`). Jeff Atwood had a [pretty decent discussion of this](http://blog.codinghorror.com/sorting-for-humans-natural-sort-order/), but it didn't address SQL sorting. That said, these are my thoughts:

- Incorporating the magnitude awareness while also retaining the ability to sort alpha characters ASCII-betically may also come in handy
- Non-alphanumeric characters would probably have to be sorted ASCII-betically regardless
- Decimal point awareness might be more effort than it's worth, since most of the time periods and commas in alphanumeric fields are treated as merely punctuation/separators, and only denote fractional portions when they're representing a float field

### My Question

**What is a reasonably flexible, reasonably generic, reasonably efficient, approach to implementing a natural sort algorithm for SQL?** Weighing the pros and cons, which is the best approach? Is there another option?

- Is there a native SQL way to `ORDER BY [field] NATURAL DESC` or something?
- PURE SQL function to create a 'sort equivalent' - Could be used to create some sort of second, possibly indexed, 'sort value' column, or called from a stored procedure, or specified in an 'ORDER BY' clause - but how to write it efficiently? (loops? is there a set based solution at all??)
- CLR SQL Function - usability benefits of pure SQL function, but using procedural language, like C# (algorithm should be no problem, but can it be made to go faster than a pure SQL sort [set based??] implementation?) Also, could be referenced and utilized in C# if efficient enough.
- Avoid SQL Server - since parsing an arbitrary number of numbers amid all sorts of other characters is really best suited for looping or recursion, and T-SQL is not well suited for looping or recursion (though TECHNICALLY supported, All I see is 'DON'T USE LOOPS!!!' and 'CTE's are even worse!!!')
- Some sort of comparator in SQL(??) - doesn't seem like SQL lends itself to that sort of sorting and I don't see a way to specify a comparator to use - so I guess this won't work...

I have values at least as varied as the following:

```
100s455t
200s400
d399487
S0000005.2
d400400
d99222
cg9876
D550-9-1
CL2009-3-27
f2g099
f2g100
f2g1000
f2g999
cg 8837
99s1000f
```

These should be sorted as follows:

```
99s1000f
100s455t
200s400
cg9876
cg 8837
CL2009-3-27
D550-9-1
d99222
d399487
d400400
f2g099
f2g100
f2g999
f2g1000
S0000005.2
```

Comment: why would cg9876 come before cg 8837?

Comment: @TabAlleman that _could_ be a false assumption on my part (treating spaces as punctuation)- looking in one source (Windows Explorer) would seem to agree a space should come before, I'll try one or two more and perhaps correct it - the key is considering numbers as _numbers_ - not as text, even though they're in the middle of text

Comment: @TabAlleman - I checked [this alphabetical order tool](http://www.textfixer.com/tools/alphabetical-order.php) and _it_ agrees with my original ordering (space after numbers) when doing the closest to what I consider to be a "natural sort" that it performs - but again, punctuation is arguable in far more venues than the magnitude of numbers vs the ASCII value of the characters that make them up (which has more consensus) - I think I'll leave it, butI appreciate you bringing it up

Comment: Well you could write a UDF that takes the column value and pads all the number-parts with enough zeros that they sort alphabetically, and replaces the spaces with an ascii character that falls where you want it to in the alphabetical order as well.

Comment: @TabAlleman - that assumes knowing how big the biggest number you'll have to compare is, wouldn't it? turning `m20-998-00` into `m020-998-000` is fine until the middle number gets to four digits: `b199-1002-020` would go before it, but naturally, it would be expected to go after. and making all numbers 12 or 20 digits could be problematic... (e.g. `m000000000020-000000000998-000000000000`, etc) -- There are all sorts of problems with context of numbers that would have to remain moot (e.g. Q: "what if the numbers represent a date?" A: "too bad", *or* "try using ISO date format")

Comment: `All I see is 'DON'T USE LOOPS!!!' and 'CTE's are even worse!!!'` CTEs are not worse if used correctly, but don't use loops.

Comment: I don't agree that treat any number as a number in character field is natural.  If it is numeric then put it in a numeric field.  > < operators are still going to follow the collation.

Comment: @hogan - I might have exaggerated, but after fifteen minutes, nothing was dawning on me as to how to use CTEs efficiently to parse a string recursively, and it's the only recursive thing in SQL I could think of - Please feel free to offer a CTE that works (even if it's not efficient)

Comment: @Blam A bunch of people do, especially in the context of codes like model numbers, room/building numbers, and all other sorts of lists of things that have qualitative and ranked aspects (chapter, volume, edition, version, location, etc) - especially when the qualitative portion is variable and unanticipated, and at least _wasn't_ built into the schema at or near the beginning of development. Room number might be a good example; if you're going to make a generic 'bucket' for rooms, you can't know how many different ways users may classify them (building, floor, numbers, letters, punctuation, ?)

Comment: @CodeJockey - I would not parse a string with a CTE.  I think the most efficient would be a CLR user defined function in C# https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2kae45k%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

Comment: The reason you are having issues here is because you have multiple values stored in a single column. This violates 1NF and causes all sorts of issues, sorting being one of them.

Comment: A CLR will be the best performance wise for sure. check out this article for a number of different splitters and performance tests of each. http://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings

Comment: No they don't.   If there no structure to a model number then you have no basis to assume A1 is before A09.    Where model >= "a1" is not going honor this 'natural sort'.  Don't make a generic bucket for rooms and then guess what syntax means.   Why would you even have a database app if you are going to have a generic bucket?

Comment: @SeanLange yes! Correct! And yet... the problem remains and needs a solution

Comment: For most people saying there are deeper problems - that's correct! Bad design! No! - - - A bunch of user provided, arbitrarily complex, can't-agree-on-anything-except-length-and-character-set data is a key field upon which everyone wants to be able to sort "naturally" - what's the best way? CLR is pulling into the lead!

Comment: Really arbitrarily complex data is a good design?   If they agree on length then why is the sample set not the same length.  So you give them an (un)natural sort.  How do you follow up with an (un)natural search?  You cant even get 1NF data design and you think the fix is a custom sort?

Comment: user defined information that contains more than 1 data element is NOT a key. It is painful and leads to the very type of thing you are struggling with. I would politely disagree that allowing users to have any say in what a key is by its nature bad design.

Comment: As you have discovered you are going to have to parse this into the two actual values. The real challenge here is that you don't even have delimited data. It isn't going to be fun and performance can get really painful if you have a lot of data.

Comment: @blam maybe the data isn't quite this complex, but imagine it's the field in a database that represents the title of a cook book. In the real situation, there is significantly less space (max length) available and artistic freedom demonstrated, but the data is that flexible. In response to customer complaints, "my client", the bookseller, wants customers to be able to sort a list of cook book titles such that , e.g. "99 Omelette Recipes" appears before, rather than after, "100 Ways to Crack an Egg". Also, each book he sells has exactly 100 recipes - even his edition of Moby Dick

Comment: We can agree all day about how it's bad design, but as with most things, significant overhaul of the design is not on the plate for this particular meal.

Comment: @SeanLange key as in "highly utilized by users of the system". Not as in "unique in the design of the database"

Comment: Imagine a consistent question.  The length fixed or not.  A magic sort is not a magic search.   Where recipes > 99 Omelettes is not going to find 100 Omelettes.

Comment: @blam I assume you mean the posted question (?) Not sure what you're saying is inconsistent (?). If the user navigates to a list of ten books (via search or category narrowing or whatever) containing cook books themed on egg recipes and is viewing a summary list, that list should be sortable by, among other things, title. These titles have numbers in them. The bookseller is not going to require the authors to rename their books, set a short limit on title length or enter in meta data to describe how the books should be sorted. This information needs to be determined automatically.

Comment: This information could be determined with a procedural language, using any combination of many many algorithms freely available on the internet, either in a bulk process, on entry, on demand during sorting, just prior to display - whatever makes the most sense. The data is currently in a SQL Server Database table, lumped into a single field and is being displayed in the wild, to customers, but is not being sorted according to customer expectations. If SQL Server had this capability, that would be ideal. It doesn't. What is the closest we can get to that ideal solution? What are the drawbacks?

Comment: Assume I mean agree with your won statements "A bunch of user provided, arbitrarily complex, can't-agree-on-anything-except-length-and-character-set"   Really I am going to have two books "My 99 Omelets" and my "My 100 Omelets" and need 99 to sort first.  What if I have my "My 2nd Edition 99 Omelets"  where does it sort?  And you still have not responded to the issue of  where title >  "My 99 Omelets"  will not return "My 99 Omelets" .

Comment: @blam within the context of programming in general, this is not a magic sort. Most procedural languages do not support it natively, but there is an implementation freely available for each of them, usually with some sort of commentary on how it's not perfect, or doesn't account for something, and/or is not efficient. The most common name for these is "natural" SQL is not a procedural language, and T-SQL is not recommended for processing lots of loops, which are AFAIK necessary for this sort of algorithm. I can't find, but could use, and am trying to determine a SQL solution.

Comment: No there is not a procedural language that supports your (un)natural sort.  Character is not a number. For the 5th time a SQL magic solution sort does not fix the the SQL where.

Comment: You can see troll but you can't see 1NF.  Get glasses.

Comment: Don't take a chance.  At this point I don't want to help you.

Answer (score 1):

Create a sort column. That way you can keep all the usual mechanisms in place that you use today to sort. You can index that column for example.

Split the string into parts. You need to pad number parts with zeroes to the maximum possible number length.

For example `CL2009-3` would become `CL|000002009|-|000000003`.

This way the usual case-insensitive SQL Server collation sort behavior will create the right order.

Doing a natural sort dynamically prevents indexing, requires the entire data set to move into the app for each query and is resource intensive.

Instead, simply update the sort column whenever you update the base column.

Comment: Though it would achieve the ordering I need, I can't think that padding the numbers could be made to be dependable enough, because the numbers could be every other character, thus making something like `a1b2c3d4e5` into `a0000001b0000002c0000003d0000004e0000005` - I could of course make the sort field big enough to handle this situation with 10 padding digits, but that would lack support for 11 or 12 digit numbers... However I am working toward creating a "sort" column, so it can be indexed, and I think I've come up with an encoding scheme - I have a feeling it will need an answer of my own

Comment: @CodeJockey Why don't you just set the column length to the maximum allowed which would be 900 for varchar and 450 for nvarchar?

Comment: ah - this MIGHT work... somehow I thought the limit on a varchar was in the 250 range, but 8,000 should be plenty of space to give - what I need to do now is figure out if I want to use my encoding scheme, which would be more processing, or use more space to store the sort value

Comment: Index keys are limited to 900 bytes.

Comment: ah - good to know that too, I saw the limit for a varchar - in general perhaps ? - as 8,000, but 900 should still be enough.

Comment: @CodeJockey I have created a question to solicit proposals for a better encoding: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28413947/space-efficient-way-to-encode-numbers-as-sortable-strings

Comment: I put my encoding scheme more or less into words in response to your referenced question, but that question does not take into account alphanumeric strings - only numbers encoded as strings - not sure if that was intentional, as your question seemed to be in response to this comment thread, and this thread talks about alphanumeric strings (?)

Comment: That was intentional because with the encoding I proposed (string parts separated by `|`) numbers can be treated separately. Or can't they?!

Comment: Or, create a multi-column index. Like this: (Part0 string, Part1 int, Part2 string, Part3 int, ...). SQL Server supports up to 16 such columns. You could make the last column use this special encoding, or just give up and declare 16 columns to be good enough.

Answer (score 0):

OK. Here is something that is *almost* what you are looking for. The only piece it can't deal with is when there are some characters then a space and then numbers (cg 8837 and cg9876). Would be good if in the future you could post the ddl and sample data so we can work with it.

```
with Something (SomeValue) as(
    select '100s455t' union all
    select '200s400' union all
    select 'd399487' union all
    select 'S0000005.2' union all
    select 'd400400' union all
    select 'd99222' union all
    select 'cg9876' union all
    select 'D550-9-1' union all
    select 'CL2009-3-27' union all
    select 'f2g099' union all
    select 'f2g100' union all
    select 'f2g1000' union all
    select 'f2g999' union all
    select 'cg 8837' union all
    select '99s1000f'
)

select * 
from Something
order by
    cast(
    case when patindex('%[A_Za-z]%', SomeValue) = 1 then '99999999999'
         when patindex('%[A_Za-z]%', SomeValue) = 0 then SomeValue
         else substring(SomeValue, 1, patindex('%[A_Za-z]%', SomeValue) - 1)
    end as bigint),
    SomeValue
```

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend to "stay away from the SQL Server". While technically you can implement everything using t-sql or clr function, SQL server remains a single non scalable unit of the infrastructure. Using its CPU resources to do a heavy computing is going to inevitably impact performance of the system in general. And in the end, SQL server will be performing sort using almost exactly the same algorithm that you will use to sort your array on the application side, i.e. looking at each item in array and comparing it to the others until it finds an appropriate position.

Of course I am assuming that, if you try to implement this type of sort on the SQL server side, you will be copying the data into a temporary table before performing the sort, to avoid data locks etc.